# HTTP POST Request, 400 bad request error

Tags: http, post, http-status-code-400

I am having a problem with HTTP requests. I keep getting a 400 error.

The service I'm trying to access is expecting a JSON body with the following format:

```
{
    "items":[{
        "id":0,
        "modifiers":[],
        "note":"",
        "quantity":0
    }],
    "type":0
}
```

Where `0` can be any number really.  However, the request that my application is sending is formatted like this.

```
{
    "items":[{
        "id":0,
        "note":"",
        "modifiers":[],
        "quantity":0
    }],
    "type":0
}
```

Could this be the cause of the 400 HTTP Request error code that I keep getting?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the error reason. Order of the json key:value doesn't matter.
You could check this link to find out error reason:

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the JSON issue(well what I thought was an issue) and pointing me in the right direction.  Much appreciated.